# How to solve a 2D Poisson's equation in cylindrical coordinates using finite difference

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, parabolic-pde

I am trying to solve the following PDE using finite difference approximations,

$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2T}{\partial\theta^2}  = 0$$ $$0 ≤  ≤ 1, 0 ≤  ≤ 2$$
$$(1, ) = 100 \sin()$$

Are there any thoughts of how can I discretize this PDE?

New update:
I have tried to simplify the problem into a 2D-plate-like problem, the temperature distribution may look like:
[image]

Comment: Your boundary condition does not depend on $\theta$. In this case you can suppose radial symmetry, i.e. the second term zero, which simplifies the game. In this case you solve only dependence of $T=T(r)$ on $[0,1]$, where you also have to consider the obvious condition $\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}(0)=0$. Then you do discretization using a standard difference formula and you get a linear system of equations as a result.

Comment: @VítězslavŠtembera
I am afraid that I will need to solve a 2D problem that depends on r and θ.

Comment: If so, it would be good to adapt your problem description so that it is evident, where the dependency on $\theta$ comes to play. Your boundary conditions are radially symmetric. What about loading or heat sources?

Comment: @VítězslavŠtembera
Please kindly take a look at this picture:
[https://ibb.co/Sd2Wrzv](https://ibb.co/Sd2Wrzv)
It illustrates the given data of this  problem.

Comment: Aha, I see, ok, in your description there is a slider... It is clear now. Is it a test to an exam?

Comment: @VítězslavŠtembera
No, it's not. It is a problem given in a programming class to practice MATLAB. I am trying to understand the theory to formulate the code. We are given some instructions as illustrated in [https://ibb.co/xJQwfXg](https://ibb.co/xJQwfXg).